# Can't login to Office 365. Getting a blank password screen

Tags: outlook, office365

I am unable to login to office.com.  When I go to login I am getting the following image:
[image]

The login URL is:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=4765445b-32c6-49b0-83e6-1d93765276ca&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.office.com%2Flandingv2&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.office.com%2Fv2%2FOfficeHome.All&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637927436232610359.MDgxNGQyZmUtZjg0Ni00ODcwLTllNzMtZTBmNjU5NWM0N2E1NWFiMzcyNTYtNWM0MC00OWJlLTg3ZTItZjFkOWZiM2IxMzg4&ui_locales=en-US&mkt=en-US&client-request-id=a1e7e5a8-74a1-4905-bf42-e2c89323b8df&state=-zy44XR3sotYXXQ0YUfXc4sUj-ebEQme7Wpholgz-6tZymVYWHQetYAEAHDR5fpJiQKlcKnZL1RiKN_Df28zr-kgl2q-fzAFU6c2aFQR3kkVc5Dkry_f6J9EgAxCqOBV60RMhD0uqf1Ot2v50Ra362pj1lXyCkD23M7QtgFTsb8e-2KmL6XdHBIOh_VeuhVQPfCiHol-WBhyeUZaGYAkvUIWFtq-rtPfnvTLTZE8lh_-h6wp3taNNSF19MT6eqsNgr3b6TLHDDaMCEb-CVvR9YOkuzYGrNz8fVoZbvEGLgQ&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.12.1.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried opening your link and it's working fine.

You can try the following things:

1 - Try logging in incognito and check if you get the same result

2 - Update the browser to the latest version

3 - Try using a different browser

4 - Try using a different device

Comment: Turns out just waiting an hour resolved the problem.  It was something on microsoft's end.  I tried login on my phone, and two different PCs and like 7 browsers.  After an hour I tried again and everything was working fine. idk what happened.

Comment: That's weird! Now you know how to fix this issue